# How do you search a deep multidimentional array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**TL;DR on bottom**

I'm making a website where you add your own goals, but each of those goals can have their own goals, and they theirs etc.

Now I figured out how to get an array/eloquent collection with the goal info and all the subgoals, but I can't figure out how to best search it.

Here is a sample of the array I'm working with:

```
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Set up a budget
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:22:57
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:22:57
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Set up a budget
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:22:57
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:22:57
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $100
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:21
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:21
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $100
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:21
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:21
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => App\Goal Object
                                (
                                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [connection:protected] => sqlite
                                    [table:protected] => goals
                                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                                    [keyType:protected] => int
                                    [incrementing] => 1
                                    [with:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [withCount:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                                    [exists] => 1
                                    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                            [goal_id] => 3
                                            [objective] => Set aside $100 each payday
                                            [completed] => 0
                                            [completed_at] => 
                                            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:25:23
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:25:23
                                        )

                                    [original:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                            [goal_id] => 3
                                            [objective] => Set aside $100 each payday
                                            [completed] => 0
                                            [completed_at] => 
                                            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:25:23
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:25:23
                                        )

                                    [changes:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [casts:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dates:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dateFormat:protected] => 
                                    [appends:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [observables:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [relations:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [goals] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                                                (
                                                    [items:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [touches:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [timestamps] => 1
                                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [visible:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $250
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:32
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:32
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $250
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:32
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:32
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $500
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:39
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:39
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $500
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:39
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:23:39
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $1000
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:24:13
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:24:13
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $1000
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:24:13
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:24:13
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
App\Goal Object
(
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [connection:protected] => sqlite
    [table:protected] => goals
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $10000
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:24
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:24
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [user_id] => 1
            [goal_id] => 1
            [objective] => Save $10000
            [completed] => 0
            [completed_at] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:24
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:24
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [childrenRecursive] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => App\Goal Object
                                (
                                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [connection:protected] => sqlite
                                    [table:protected] => goals
                                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                                    [keyType:protected] => int
                                    [incrementing] => 1
                                    [with:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [withCount:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                                    [exists] => 1
                                    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                            [goal_id] => 8
                                            [objective] => Invest my savings
                                            [completed] => 0
                                            [completed_at] => 
                                            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:50
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:50
                                        )

                                    [original:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                            [goal_id] => 8
                                            [objective] => Invest my savings
                                            [completed] => 0
                                            [completed_at] => 
                                            [created_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:50
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-11-28 16:27:50
                                        )

                                    [changes:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [casts:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dates:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dateFormat:protected] => 
                                    [appends:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [observables:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [relations:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [goals] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                                                (
                                                    [items:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => App\Goal Object

                                                                    [changes:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [casts:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [dates:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [dateFormat:protected] =>
```

What I want from this array is an array of ALL the unique instances of `[id] => x`. It's because when you complete one goal, all subgoals should be force completed as well, but the parent goals obviously.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I got the array/object in the OP:

```
public function complete(\app\goal $goal)
{
    $children = $goal->find($goal->id)->goals()->with('childrenrecursive')->get();

    foreach($children as $key => $item)
    {
        echo "<pre>", print_r($item), "</pre>";
    }

    die();
}
```

What I need is an array with all the unique IDs of the goals from $children so when I mark a goal as completed, all children, grandchildren and so on will be marked completed as well. If I get an array of all the IDs I can run a foreach loop and mark each of them completed

**UPDATE 2**
Here is how my goal model is:

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToUser(User::class);
    }

    public function goals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Goal::class, 'goal_id');
    }

    public function childrenRecursive()
    {
        return $this->goals()->with('goals');
    }


}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Database sample

```
id          user_id     goal_id     objective   completed 
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1                       Get rich    0         
2           1           1           Set up a b  1         
3           1           1           Save $100   1         
4           1           1           Save $250   1         
5           1           1           Save $500   1         
6           1           1           Save $1000  1         
7           1           3           Set aside   0         
8           1           1           Save $1000  1         
9           1           8           Invest my   0         
10          1           9           Buy stock   0         
11          1           9           Buy gold    0         
12          1           9           Buy bitcoi  0         
13          1           10          Buy 5x AMD  0         
14          1           10          Buy 5x Int  0         
15          1           8           Donations   0         
16          1           15          Donate to   0         
17          1           15          Send a tha  0         
18          1           8           Start anot  0         
19          1           16          Check out   0         
20          1           19          Check if m  0         
21          1           19          Find out w  0         
22          1           21          Make sure   0         
23          1           22          But if it   0         
24          1           23          Avoid hero  0
```

Comment: It's not an array. It's an object of type `App\Goal`. Maybe this helps. And if `App\Goal` extends `Model` class from laravel you can call `toArray()` to get an array

Comment: What have you tried before? Show us some code...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've updated the post. `\App\Goal` does extend to `Model` - can you show me how to do the `toArray()` thing?

Comment: `$goal->find($goal->id)` makes no sense. With `find` you get the same object from DB that you already have. Remove the `find` call and try directly `$goal->goals()`. That saves DB requests

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I added it for testing and forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$children` is of type `Collection`. And `Collection` has many awesome functions. E.g. `filter` or `map`.

In your case it could look like following:

```
// Filtering results in a new collection where only elements are included that matches the condition 
$filtered = $children->filter(function($item) use ($value) {
    return $item->getKey() === 'x'; 
});

// Mapping let's you change each element in the collection. This example returns an array with only the IDs
$childrenIds = $children->map(function($item) {
    return $item->getKey();
});
```

But if just want to update the goal and subgoals try directly updating the relation and the model itself

```
$goal->goals()->update(['completed' => 1]); // children
$goal->update(['completed' => 1]); // parent
```

Here is the full documentation: [Laravel Documentation: Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter)

Comment: `$goal->goals()->update(['completed' => 1]);` would be the perfect thing, but for some reason it only updates the children, not the grandchildren etc. I'll add another update with the goal model

Comment: Yes, there is no way to update the parent and the children with one line of code. You must do both. Update parent and then update children. Both are two tables, so you need two update queries. That is done with two lines of code.

Comment: $goal is one item in the db, and $goal->goals() are the items linked to $goal, but there are also goals linked to goals linked to goals before its linked back to the original. I want to be able to nest infinetly without having to write a foreach loop for every level in the nesting. I'm sorry I'm having so much trouble explaining it right

Comment: I added a sample of the database

Comment: You mean your table is recursively build. All goals are in the same table linked with itself over a column e.g. `parent`. MySQL is not the best choice when using recursive structures. Then you have to build many logic in code. MSSQL and many other database implementions have direct support for recursive queries. But then I think there is no logic in Laravel to support those features. So, if you are using recursive Tables you have to do a lot to get it running

Comment: Oh... I've just started learning laravel so suppose I'll remove the infinite nesting, then. That's very disappointing though, recursive posts is a cool feature. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No, you can use it. It's possible. But then you need much more experiences with Laravel to get it run. You will do it. Maybe if you are googling `recursive queries with laravel` or `recursive tables...` you'll find the exakt solution.